# Javascript: detect site for media queries?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to detect media queries with javascript with out using Modernizr and similar libraries? I only need to see if media queries are there and maybe which widths.

**EDIT:**
My problem. I am making a chrome extension that need to be able to see if the current site is using media queries without having to re-size the viewport.

In a nut shell I just want to check if a site is using media queries with javascript alone. is that possible?

Comment: Just measure `someElement.offsetWidth` and compare to that specified for a particular media?

Comment: You want to detect whether the site's stylesheet(s) use Media Queries?

Comment: yes I want to detect if the site is using media queries.

Comment: @delboud Excuse my delay, but what problem are you trying to solve? I'm a little confused by your question.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking for `CSSMediaRule` objects within the `document.styleSheets` collection. For example, the Modernizr website uses media queries, and we know this, so we can check by examining their stylesheet objects:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules; // CSSRuleList
```

Within this list we simply look for any `CSSMediaRule`; we happen to find 3 on their site.

Comment: This seems like a good solution but how accurate is it? I went to bootstrap site and say no `CSSMediaRule`'s

Comment: Ok i looked at the second sheet and found it, I didnt think of looping through the different sheets. This helps a lot!

Comment: Quick question Jonathan, how do I know in JS code if the type is a CSSMediaRule object or some other?

Comment: @krislogy You can test with `instanceof CSSMediaRule`.